# ASP.NET MVC Text Fields not sent to model when form contains Files and Text Fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I have developed a form where the form fields contain `type=text` fields and `type=file` fields.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFiles", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="container">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div class="card border-info col-sm-6">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UploadForm.Name, new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UploadForm.Name, "", htmlAttributes: new { @type = "text", @class = "form-control", aria_describedby = "nameHelp", placeholder = "Enter name" })
                        <small id="nameHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Name to be associated</small>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UploadForm.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UploadForm.files, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UploadForm.files, "", htmlAttributes: new { @type = "file", @multiple = "multiple", @class = "form-control-file", aria_describedby = "filesHelp" })
                        
                        <small id="filesHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Files to be uploaded</small>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UploadForm.files, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="row justify-content-end" style="margin-right:1px;">
                        <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary w-25"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
    </div>
}
```

My Controller looks as under

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFiles(HomeModel model)
{        
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        **// getting model.UploadForm.Name null here**
        **// getting model.UploadForm.files is populated and contains files**
    }
    
    return View("Index", model);
}
```

**Am I missing something ?**

Also, if anyone can tell, how can I modify controller to obtain only relevant data like as under. I tried doing this, but everything comes null.

```
UploadFiles (string name, HttpPostedFile[] files) 
{
        // both args are coming null
}
```

---

**Edit:**

This is my model as requested:

```
public class HomeModel
{
    public UploadForm UploadForm { get; set; }
    public List<UploadedItem> UploadedItems { get; set; }
}
```

and this is what UploadForm looks like

```
public class UploadForm
{
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter name.")]
    public string Name;

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select file(s).")]
    [Display(Name = "Files")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase[] files { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Show us your model.

Comment: @MrLu Updated the model in question

Comment: What do you mean modify controller to get relevant data?

Comment: at present, the UploadFiles action is getting entire model (`HomeModel`). I want to modify the action to get only relevant data (`UploadedFiles` and `Name`)

Comment: So you want to not use the HomeModel, you could just use the UploadForm as your model or skip them both and just use [HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFiles (string name, HttpPostedFile[] files), you'll have to modify your view to reflect changes.

Comment: `HomeModel` is used page wide, while for action `UploadFiles` only selected information is needed. But then the problem is that, I need to pass `HomeModel` to the `View` in case `ModelState.IsValid` is `False`. Hence I am forced to used HomeModel

Comment: Where you able to get it done? If not let me know.

Comment: @MrLu Thanks. Yes, I could get it working, so marked your answer as Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your UploadForm class, Name is missing get set

```
public class UploadForm
{
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter name.")]
    public string Name { get; set; };

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select file(s).")]
    [Display(Name = "Files")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase[] files { get; set; }
}
```